# Radio button checked status is not getting retrived

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

*I want my formData to say which radio button is selected.Basically if its 1st radio button then it should be set to true if deselected it should be false.
Currently with my below code model is not getting set.
I tried using ng-value but then it didn't work.
This is what i tried*

Basically, I want model data to set to true based on checked status.

**Html Code**

```
                            <div class="radio">

                                <input type="radio" id="typeRadio1" name="optradio" ng-model="formData.selectedType.perm" ng-change="isRadioSelected('typeRadio1')" required><label for="typeRadio1">301 PERM</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="typeRadio2" name="optradio" ng-model="formData.selectedType.temp" ng-change="isRadioSelected('typeRadio2')" required><label for="typeRadio2">302 TEMP</label>
                            </div>
```

**app.js**

```
        $scope.formData = {}
        $scope.isRadioSelected = function(s) {
            if (document.getElementById(s).checked) { $scope.formData.selectedType.perm = true; }
            else { $scope.formData.selectedType.perm = false;}

            if (document.getElementById(s).checked) { $scope.formData.selectedType.temp = true; }
            else { $scope.formData.selectedType.temp = false;
}                
        }
```

Comment: it's not radio! `checkbox` you have

Comment: you don't need `document.getElementById(s).checked` if you are passing an ng-model, e.g. `$scope.isRadioSelected(formData.name.desktop)`. Then you can simply have: `$scope.formData.selectedType.perm = s;`

Comment: try this might be helpful http://jsfiddle.net/takuan/aaoub2mg/

Answer (score 0):

When you have `checkbox` you don't need `ng-value` because you will get `true/false` but checkbox also have unique `ng-model` **but** all **Radio** has same `name` with `ng-value`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  
  $scope.checkboxSelected = function(item){
    console.log(item)
  }
  
 $scope.radioSelected = function(){
    console.log($scope.form.radio)
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  checkbox1 - {{form.checkbox1}}
  <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkboxSelected(form.checkbox1)" ng-model="form.checkbox1"/>
  
  checkbox1 - {{form.checkbox2}}
  <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkboxSelected(form.checkbox2)" ng-model="form.checkbox2"/>
  
  
  <hr>
  
  
  radio - {{form.radio}}
  <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-value="1" ng-change="radioSelected()" ng-model="form.radio"/>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-value="2" ng-change="radioSelected()" ng-model="form.radio"/>
</div>
```

Comment: even after gviving same model name...Model is not getting bind instead it always selects 2nd radio button by default. I tried below code.                                                              '<div class="radio"> <input type="radio" id="typeRadio1" name="optradio" ng-value="perm" ng-change="radioSelected()" ng-model="formData.selectedType"  required><label for="typeRadio1">301 PERM</label><input type="radio" id="typeRadio2" name="optradio" ng-value="temp" ng-change="radioSelected()" ng-model="formData.selectedType"  required><label for="typeRadio2">302 TEMP</label></div>'